# Enabling access only on google, yandex, disable direct access

Tags: php, traffic

Hello I have php website and I want visitors to come only on google yandex but disable access from direct link or direct traffic?

I do not have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google and Yandex are visitors too!

You may prohibit access for everyone and allow access for individual IP's, like the ones for the Google and Yandex crawl servers. But this means, that both search engines may be able to index your site but no user will ever be able to see your website.

This does not make any sense and may also lead to get kicked out of the Google index for the means of cloaking.

If you want to find out where a user comes from (i.e. whether an URL was requested directly or via a link from a search engine) – there is no reliable way to do this. One may parse and use the `HTTP_REFERER`, but it is up the used browser/client whether this field is set at all or set to a useful IP. Some browsers even have an option to always suppress this header.